# WAR file deployment on Tomcat7 with DNS

Tags: dns, war, tomcat7

I have an WAR file which i deployed on Tomcat 7. I can use my application by using "HTTP://192.xxx.xx.xxx:8080/TestApp/"
But i want to use my application by the address "http://www.mycompany.com/TestApp".
Also we have domain policies here in our company and also I want to make this application to be access by outside users through internet... is this possible??

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure the domain server in the company so that the mycompany.com is address is associated with your IP.

For universal internet access, you also need a valid WWW domain, recognized by external [DNS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_Name_System) servers.